# How to apply themes to winform title bar

Tags: c#, winforms

In winform application, how do I give a different (different from the blue one) form title bar color or theme to all the window forms in my application. I need all buttons including 'Close' button. Is there any workaround for this? any open source available?

Comment: You need to touch a lot of unmanaged code. Why don't you hide it and make your custom header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do drawing on Non Client Area of Winforms. This is no direct way to do this but these articles may help you.

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=customerborderform

http://www.geekswithblogs.net/kobush/articles/CustomBorderForms.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you have to hide the title bar and instead of that you should use panel and simple button.
 you can add multiple theme to it in simple way